# Why this.state is undefined in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a complete newbie in react native, react.js, and javascript. I am Android developer so would like to give RN a try.

Basically, the difference is in `onPress`;

This code shows `'undefined'` when toggle() runs:

```
class LoaderBtn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loading: false };
    }

    toggle() {
        console.log(this.state);
        // let state = this.state.loading;
        console.log("Clicked!")
        // this.setState({ loading: !state })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#468938' }} onPress={this.toggle}>
                <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

but this code works:

```
class LoaderBtn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loading: false };
    }

    toggle() {
        console.log(this.state);
        // let state = this.state.loading;
        console.log("Clicked!")
        // this.setState({ loading: !state })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#468938' }} onPress={() => {this.toggle()}}>
                <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

Can you explain me the difference, please?

In Java / Kotlin we have method references, basically it passes the function if signatures are the same, like `onPress = () => {}` and `toggle = () => {}`

But in JS it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The issue is that in the first example `toggle()` is not bound to the correct `this`.

You can either bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    ...
```

Or use an instance function (OK under some circumstances):

```
toggle = () => {
    ...
}
```

This approach requires build changes via `stage-2` or `transform-class-properties`.

The caveat with instance property functions is that there's a function created per-component. This is okay if there aren't many of them on the page, but it's something to keep in mind. Some mocking libraries also don't deal with arrow functions particularly well (i.e., arrow functions aren't on the prototype, but on the instance).

This is basic JS; [this article regarding React Binding Patterns](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) may help.

Comment: this article is exactly what i needed to understand what's going on. 
The only question is it created once per component instantiation?

Comment: i mean, i really like that property syntax, but does it affect performance?

Comment: @NickKraev Depends. Not in any meaningful way if there aren't hundreds of components on the page. In general JS is fairly fast, and there are many other React optimizations that would be more impactful than this (e.g., `shouldComponentUpdate`-type things).

Comment: Great explanation, still need to figure out a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I think what is happening is a matter of scope.  When you use `onPress={this.toggle}` this is not what you are expecting in your toggle function.  However, arrow functions exhibit different behavior and automatically bind to `this`.  You can also use `onPress={this.toggle.bind(this)}`.

Further reading -

[ES6 Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

[.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: In general you do not want to create new functions during `render`. Instead bind in the ctor or use an instance property function which is bound automatically.

Comment: Yes, excellent point.  If you use the arrow function in your render, it's creating a new function every time.  I think even the React docs recommend .bind()

Answer (score 5):

What is happening in this first example is that you have lost scope of "this".  Generally what I do is to define all my functions in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: false };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}
```

In the second example, you are using ES6 syntax which will automatically bind this (which is why this works).

Then inside of you onPress function, you need to call the function that you built.  So it would look something like this,

```
onPress={this.toggle}
```

Comment: I think you'd want `this.toggle`, otherwise it'll be executed when rendered.